# Non stop output

Tags: java, loops

I'm running the code for searching synonym. Unfortunately, the output return non-stop loop as shown below.

```
Synonym 0: pupil

Synonym 0: student

Synonym 0: pupil

Synonym 0: student

Synonym 0: pupil

Synonym 0: student

Synonym 0: pupil

Synonym 0: student

Synonym 0: pupil
.
.
.
```

Did I miss something. I've tried to store synonym retrieved in temporary variable to stop the infinite loop. But, it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

```
public class GUIsynonym extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    public void displaySynonym()
    {   

        //call wordnet library  
        RiWordnet wordnet = new RiWordnet();

        String word = lineTF.getText();

        //new search 
        Vector<String> newVec = new Vector<String>();
        String[] synset = wordnet.getAllSynsets(word, "n");
        for (int k=0; k<synset.length; k++)
        {
            newVec.add(synset[k]);

            System.out.println(newVec.toArray());

            synset[k] = new String();
            for(int i=0; i<newVec.size(); i++)
            {
                int cP = newVec.indexOf(newVec.get(i));
                if(cP !=i)
                {

                    newVec.remove(cP);

                }
            }
            printSynset(word);
        }


        printSynset(word);


        String outputSynset = "Word: " + word;


        GUIsynonymTA.append("\n");
        GUIsynonymTA.append(outputSynset);
        GUIsynonymTA.append("\n");


    }// end displaySynonym()

    public static String printSynset(String word)
    {
        //call wordnet library  
        RiWordnet wordnet = new RiWordnet();
        //call stemmer method
        PorterStemmer s = new PorterStemmer();


        Vector<String> synsetVec = new Vector<String>();
        String[] synset = wordnet.getAllSynsets(word, "n");

        for (int k=0; k<synset.length; k++)
        {
            synsetVec.add(synset[k]);

            if (!synsetVec.isEmpty())
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < synsetVec.size(); j++) 
                {
                    LinkedHashSet<String> unique = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
                    LinkedHashSet<String> dups = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
                    Vector<String> newVec = new Vector<String>();   
                    for (String a : synsetVec)
                        if (!unique.add(a))
                        {
                           dups.add(a);
                           System.out.println("Duplicate detected: " + a);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Iterator<String> it = unique.iterator();

                            while(it.hasNext())
                            {

                            unique.removeAll(dups);

                            GUIsynonymTA.append("\n");
                            GUIsynonymTA.append(" Synonym " + j + ": " + it.next());
                            GUIsynonymTA.append("\n");

                            newVec.add(a);
                            unique.addAll(newVec);
                            unique.removeAll(newVec);
                            printSynset(synsetVec.get(j));
                            }
                        }


                }
            }

            else 
                GUIsynonymTA.append("No synsets");
                //if (synsetVec.isEmpty())
                //return word;
        }
        return word;
    }//end printSynset()
```

Thank you.

Comment: whats that: for (int k=0; k unique = new LinkedHashSet();?

Comment: Seems your code is broken. It won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I edited your question, using `<pre>` doesn't work on this site, please use the `{ }` button to format code :-) This misled us showing invalid sourcecode, hence the remarks about your for-loops.

It seems that you go into infinite recursion on the call;

```
                    printSynset(synsetVec.get(j));
```

also, you make changes to the `unique` collection while you are using it's iterator. This will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks..actually i've tried to delete the line printSynset(synsetVec.get(j)); and the output seems ok. But, it's not like i want. I want the output be like this.. 

Search word: student

Synset 0: pupil

  Synset 0: student

    Synset 0: pupil

    .

    .

    .

  Synset 1: educatee

  Synset 2: schoolchild

Synset 1: educatee

Synset 2: scholar

Synset 3: bookman

That's why i try to store in temporary variable.